# How do I override the notFound template?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I found it very easy to override the outerLayout and templateError core templates, but how can I customize the individual error pages (404, 500, etc)? I've tried a few different naming options, creating files both in /lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/views/pages and in /lib/modules/apostrophe-templates/views, but anytime I hit a bad URL, I still get an error returned in the console (running this locally):

`Error: template not found: notFound.html`

Comment: Found it: needs to be here:

/lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/views/notFound.html

Guess that's one location I didn't try.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of documentation in the Apostrophe HOWTOs: http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/notFoundPage.html.